# Partially applying fst and snd using let in GHCi gives a strange type signature

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, ghci

I'm implementing a fairly vanilla binary tree, and I'm implementing an `insertWith` function, such that you can insert values by transforming existing values into their "keys" - this may allow you to, say, store a tuple of (key, value) and just compare the keys when inserting new "nodes". The implementation is the following:

```
insertWith :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> BinTree a -> a -> BinTree a
insertWith _ EmptyTree    y = Node y EmptyTree EmptyTree
insertWith f (Node x l r) y =
    case compare (f y) (f x) of
        LT -> Node x (insertWith f l y) r
        EQ -> Node x l r
        GT -> Node x l (insertWith f r y)
```

When I partially apply this with `fst` using `let` in GHCi, I get the following:

```
let insertWith_ = insertWith fst
:t insertWith_
insertWith_ :: BinTree ((), b) -> ((), b) -> BinTree ((), b)
```

However, leaving out the `let` step gives the following:

```
:t insertWith fst
insertWith fst
  :: (Ord a) => BinTree (a, b) -> (a, b) -> BinTree (a, b)
```

I think it has something to do with the (Ord b) in the type signature, but I'm just wondering why GHCi transforms the type signature like this when using let? Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: The dreaded monomorphism restriction...

Comment: MR in combination with ghci's extended defaulting, I should say.